# Input tag with Three.js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm currently working on a game with Three.js. I'm using the Web GL renderer, which takes up the entire browser window. Now I want to make a chat box, so I put an input tag inside like this

```
<input id="chatMessageDiv" type="text" value="Message..."></input>
```

and for the CSS

```
#chatMessageDiv {
    position: absolute;
}
```

My problem is I can't click on the input form to change the message. The cursor changes to the text icon but when I click nothing happens.

I tried changing the inputs z-index to 1 but that didn't work either. I don't really want to add an orbit controller or a trackball controller.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to really help you. It may be a simple z-index/position problem like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151271/placing-absolute-behind-relative-positioned-element)

Comment: Did you had OrbitControls.js or something or some controls???
this take the control of most of you handlers in chrome you F12 go to Elements -> Event Listeners, you can check the script in charge of the event Listerners. I guess you can play with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is still not solved. A reason why your input field doesn't react might be that there is a `event.preventDefault()` which prevents it from it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need put your input #chatMessageDiv before the div containing your canvas.

```
<input id="chatMessageDiv" type="text" value="Message..."></input>
<div> 
     <canvas width="1370" height="395" style="width: 1370px; height: 395px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

This is because of the behavior of the canvas.

Note: check the element div with id = info.

[Demo webgl animation cloth](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html)

[Code webgl animation cloth](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your document has some event listeners due to the Orbit Controls or others.
To fix this same issue i modified the event mousedown listener in a way that it is bound only on the canvas(scene) elements alone.

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```

Becomes :

```
var cc = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
    cc[0].addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```